# How to notify C# GUI from PHP

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I am writing a RESTful Webservice with PHP. When I change data it is very simple to update a GUI in iOS oder Android with Push Notifications on mobile devices but I haven´t found a good solution for C# desktop application on computer. The user should get these changes very quickly. (1-2 second is ok).

My question is: Is there a similar way to update the GUI in C# like push notifications?

PS: I don´t want to use a windows web service!

Comment: Depends on the type of client application you have; Windows Store and Windows Phone apps both have their own push notification services (like iOS/Android) but desktop windows applications do not have something like this. In that case, you'd have to do something like long-polling.

Comment: it will be a desktop application. Is there really no other solution then long polling? i thing this method is quiet bad in terms of resources.

Comment: Yeah, polling sucks. But what do you mean by "bad in terms of resources"? Potentially heavy bandwidth usage by your RESTful web service?

Comment: exactly. The application should handle a lot of live pollings.